# jQuery - How to get JSON array name from nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm a newbie in jQuery and JSON. I hope you can help me with my little task. I have the following JSON object structure:

```
{
    "recipe": {
        "myREAL":0,
        "mySTRING":"STRING variable",
        "myUDINT":0,
        "mybool":0,
        "ingNumber":[0,0,0,0,0],
        "ingMinimumWeight":[0,0,0,0,0],
        "ingNominalWeight":[0,0,0,0,0]
    }
}
```

I would like to get the name of the array name instead of only getting the index and the value of the index.

My output so far:

```
 Key: myREAL Value: 0
 Key: mySTRING Value: STRING variable
 Key: myUDINT Value: 0
 Key: mybool Value: 0
 Key: 0 Value: 0
 Key: 1 Value: 0
 Key: 2 Value: 0
 Key: 3 Value: 0
 Key: 4 Value: 0
 ...
```

I'm interested in such structure:

```
 Key: myREAL Value: 0
 Key: mySTRING Value: STRING variable
 Key: myUDINT Value: 0
 Key: mybool Value: 0
 ingNumber:
 Key: 0 Value: 0
 Key: 1 Value: 0
 Key: 2 Value: 0
 Key: 3 Value: 0
 Key: 4 Value: 0
 ingMinimumWeight:
 ...
```

I would like to do it in Jquery without specifiying the name of the array variable.

My jQuery code:

```
function iter(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof (obj[key]) == 'object') {
            iter(obj[key]);
        } else {
            content = " Key: " + key + " Value: " + obj[key] + '\n';
            var box = $("#myArea");
            box.val(box.val() + content);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to give a title for the array output dynamically. As you can see in my JSON object the arrayname is ingNumber, ingMinimumWeight...
if i didn't specify a title i would just get Key = number, Value = number, all the way. It wouldn't look good on the console. Everytime it meets an array, i want it to first print the name of the array and thereafter print the key and values.

Comment: @user3000138 you just need to include box.val() inside the object if condition as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your desired output, you need to add content to box in before recursively calling the function again.

```
function iter(obj) {
     var box = $("#myArea");
     for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof (obj[key]) == 'object') {
            content = key+ " : \n";
            box.val(box.val() + content);
            iter(obj[key]);
        } else {
            content = " Key: " + key + " Value: " + obj[key] + '\n';
            box.val(box.val() + content);
        } 
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kefiruseke/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.append()` (you are using Jquery right?) the property name to the textarea if you are dealing with an object. Also use `===` to check if you are dealing with an object. Also check if `obj[key]` is not `null` because `typeof null` evaluates as an object too.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vatazoep/3/)

```
function iter(obj) {
    var box = $("#myArea");
    for (var key in obj) {

        if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            box.append(key+': \n')
            iter(obj[key]);
        } else {
            content = " Key: " + key + " Value: " + obj[key] + '\n'; 
            box.append(content);
        } 
    }
}
```